# EMgucv save multiple face detected from webcam

Tags: c#, emgucv, face-recognition

I have window application which will detect multiple face and capture the face and save as image.  I use the EMGU CV to do the face detection,  I learn from the sample code and tutorial.  When it need to capture the face as a trained dataset, it only able to store one face although it detected 2 faces.  I try to modify the code but it seem like not work as expected.  Below is the code:

```
 gray = grabber.QueryGrayFrame().Resize(320, 240, 
 Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);

MCvAvgComp[][] facesDetected = gray.DetectHaarCascade(
            face,
            1.2,
            10,
            Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING,
            new Size(20, 20));

foreach (MCvAvgComp f in facesDetected[0])
{
    TrainedFace = currentFrame.Copy(f.rect).Convert<Gray, byte>();

    TrainedFace = result.Resize(100, 100, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);
    trainingImages.Add(TrainedFace);

    for (int i = 1; i < trainingImages.ToArray().Length + 1; i++)
    {
        trainingImages.ToArray()[i - 1].Save(Application.StartupPath + "/TrainedFaces/face" + i + ".bmp");

    }
}
```

The foreach loop will loop twice when 2 faces detected, but the face save is the same.  Any idea what's go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

please try the following way

For Each of the faces detected, you will have to add it to training images 
and you need to loop it out side of the for each loop

```
gray = grabber.QueryGrayFrame().Resize(320, 240, 
Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);

MCvAvgComp[][] facesDetected = gray.DetectHaarCascade(
        face,
        1.2,
        10,
        Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING,
        new Size(20, 20));

foreach (MCvAvgComp f in facesDetected[0])
{
TrainedFace = currentFrame.Copy(f.rect).Convert<Gray, byte>();

TrainedFace = result.Resize(100, 100, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);
trainingImages.Add(TrainedFace);
}

 for (int i = 1; i < trainingImages.ToArray().Length + 1; i++)
{
    trainingImages.ToArray()[i - 1].Save(Application.StartupPath + "/TrainedFaces/face" + i + ".bmp");

 }
```

I think the for loop could be changed to

```
int i=1;
foreach(TrainedFace Tface in trainingImages)
  {
   Tface.Save(Application.StartupPath + "/TrainedFaces/face" + i + ".bmp")
    i++;
   }
```

Please try this way,it might work ..

Comment: I tried and still the same.  Although detected 2 different faces in the camera and it draw 2 red rectangle.  The foreach looping twice but it save the same face.